# Macro to Convert a Bulleted List to SmartArt in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to convert a previously selected bulleted list to SmartArt in MS Word.
I am a novice on VBA, but I got following code to creat a SmartArt:

```vb
Sub Macro2()
Dim myShape As Shape
Dim mySmartArt As SmartArt
Set myShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddSmartArt(Application.SmartArtLayouts(2), 100, 100, 400, 400)
Set mySmartArt = myShape.SmartArt
End Sub
```

Thanks for your attention and help

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more details. For example images of your list and smart art (done manually) so that people here can have an idea of what you're trying to achieve. Also, have you tried the macro recorder? It's sometimes good to start with code generated by the macro recorder and edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: You'll need to define this a little more. As an example, SmartArt can multiple levels that correspond to different outline levels of a bulleted list. Does that need to be handled, or are all your bulleted list a single level?